# What type of php code is this?

Tags: php

[image]

I’ve been learning some php and SQL, and I’ve hired a freelancer on Upwork to help with a project. He’s been a little sketchy the past few days, and then I get some files like this from him. What kind of php code is this supposed to be? Just seems strange, and nobody I’ve asked seems to know. Thanks!

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted real code/string instead of image. its encoded but its php code. either he wanted to hide his code or he is really sketchy. my guess is he doesnt have good intention. since you posted image i cant decode it

Comment: I'll edit it and post the code. I just didn't want to take a chance of posting anything malicious.

Comment: It's apparently too much code for the post. I'll just assume it's sketchy and delete it. Was just looking for some confirmation. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that's unusual. Looks like he has something to hide, especially with it all compressed like that.

Answer (score 1):

\x is the escape character for a hexadecimal representation, with the two characters following being the hex code.

Take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) to see the common escape characters